# Google Firebase authentication: What is the server Client's ID that's passed requestIdToken

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented google sign-in with firebase authentication by following a tutorial that tells me what to do but offers no explanation on what I am actually doing.
Even though the app works, I have been trying to understand what the code actually does.
I have been reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) but couldn't understand everything.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                // TODO : What is IdToken
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

I have read everything about the ***requestIdToken***, but I couldn't understand its role in the sign-in flow.
What I found is :

> You must pass your server's client ID to the requestIdToken method.

And this is information about [server's client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id) (Click on the link).

Despite reading all of that, I couldn't get what the ***requestIdToken*** function does and what is the ***server's client ID***

Can someone please explain these?

Answer (score 1):

After a long day of trying to understand how google sign-in works and diving into a research rabbit hole, I kind of began to understand what this is all about.

When the user signs-in, I **request the user's ID** by passing [**my authentication server's web Client ID**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id) to the **requestIdToken** method .It can be used later on to verify the identity of the [**currently signed-in user**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).